# Build UI for complex object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, razor

I'm planning to build an UI and I'm looking for best practices to achieve this in .net core 3.1 with MVC and Razor.
The UI is separated in two regions: on the left side a navigation and the rest is the content. The content depends on the selected navigation menu.

The object which is displayed by this view is a big/complex object with several sub objects.
My navigation for this object could be the following abstracted tree structure:

**TopLevel Object**

-- Common

---- Group 1

------ Sub-Object 1 (Class A)

------ Sub-Obejct 2 (Class A)

------ Sub-Object 3 (Class A)

------ ...

------ Sub-Object 9 (Class A)

---- Group 2

------ Sub-Object 10 (Class B)

------ Sub-Object 11 (Class B)

------ Sub-Object 12 (Class B)

....

------ Sub-Object 15 (Class B)

The fields to edit are different for Common, Group 1, Object of Class A, Group 2 and Objects of Class B.
My first idea was to separate the sub UIs in several partial views and show the correct partial view depending on the selection of the selected navigation entry.

But I'm not sure if this will be the best way. Therefore I'm looking for ideas whats the best practice to build a editable UI for such a big/complex object.

I'm happy for any ideas and any hints. :-)

Thanks
Boris

Comment: Are you using Layout View ?

Comment: Yes, but the structure above is not the top level menu structure! That should be the structure in a an editable subview.